# Why formatting data is not working Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I use the following pattern:

```
 {{ item.EVPDATA | date: "dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm" }}
```

Value `item.EVPDATA` is UNIX time `1566473370`:

I get formatted data as:

```
 19.07.1970 07:07
```

Why I get wrong data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data is in unix time, so before passing it to Date pipe you need to convert it to Date timestamp (by *1000), below code should work -

```
{{ (item.EVPDATA * 1000) | date: "dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM"}}
```

[**Stackblitz Working Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-unix?file=src/app/app.component.html)

For more shorthand pipe values for Date you can refer -

- https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1):

try:
 {{ item.EVPDATA | date: "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" }}

Comment: It still gives me `19.07.1970 07:07`

Comment: It should return me `Thu, 22 Aug 2019 11:29:30 GMT` in format

Comment: you can use date: 'full', or date: "EEEE, MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a zzzz"

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs for the DatePipe:
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Have you tried this:

```
{{ item.EVPDATA * 1000 | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a zzzz' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({
  name: "mypipe"
})
export class MyPipe  implements PipeTransform {
  transform(unix: any): string {
    const time = new Date(unix * 1000)
    return time.toString();
  }
}

{{ item.EVPDATA | mypipe }}
```

See [the sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kinsqn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)